# rename text from file ,and string batch file

Tags: batch-file

i have a lot of folders , with in then there are files with name : XXXX_transcoded.j2c

i need to remove the _transcoded.j2c from the file and update to XXXX.txt

anyone have any idead how to do it

here my code so far

```
for /r %%i in (*.j2c) do (
call:Set %%~ni
)   

:Set
set currenttext=%*
set currenttext=%currenttext:_transcoded=%
echo %currenttext%
%%~ni.Contract.xml %%i.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_transcoded.j2c" '
  ) DO (
  SET "fullname=%%a"
  SET "oldname=%%~nxa"
  CALL :changename
)

GOTO :EOF

:changename
SET "newname=%oldname:_transcoded.j2c=%"
ECHO REN "%fullname%" "%newname%.txt"

GOTO :eof
```

This should work for you. You'd have to set your directory into `sourcedir`.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Of course, you could also put `.txt` into the string replacement expression (instead of into `REN`). Or you could put the expression into `REN` directly. On an entirely different note, I've been meaning to ask you for quite some time: is DOS really a language? :)

Comment: @AndriyM: Well, it's a language - but `DOS` is a generic term, so you'd inevitably get a degree of flak from the terminology freaks. Whatever term you use, you'd be likely to offend against the sensibilities of someone who's spoiling for an argument. Personally, I call it "Batch" - but strictly, that's inaccurate too.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /s /b /a-d *_transcoded.j2c'
) do (
  set "full=%%F"
  set "name=%%~nxF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!full!" "!name:~0,-15!.txt"
  endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need.  Test it on some sample files.

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*_transcoded.j2c) do (
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nxi") do ren "%%i" "%%a.txt"
)
```

Comment: If I'm entirely honest, I think this is slightly less reliable compared to the other two suggestions. (What if there's another `_` before `_transcoded`?) The idea is very clear, though, and the implementation elegant and succinct.

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, it could fail in such cases - and as you know batch code is often written for the circumstances it is used in. Getting real details about the task and filenames is like pulling teeth a lot of the time. :)  They haven't made any comment so one of the solutions worked.